# Which connection does that data stream use after VPN disconnects

Tags: windows-7, video-streaming, vpn, netflix

I am wondering which connection gets stuck with the data charges in the following situation:

1 Windows 7 PC with default VPN connection active
- connect to video streaming service to watch a movie
- disconnect the vpn (stream keeps running)

Now, for some types of VPN you get charged for quantity of data and I am wondering if in the above situation the data used by the video stream is charged to the VPN. Is there a way to check?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically, as soon as you disconnect the VPN connection, traffics flow over your ISP but to make sure if it's still passing through your VPN gateway you can utilize `tracert` command on windows to get a trace of the route that packets take to reach the destination.

e.g. `tracert www.hulu.com`

You can also use an IP address instead of a DNS name.